# How can I create a list using elements from other alternating lists?

Tags: python-3.x

Essentially I'm new to python (and coding in general) and I'm trying to make a simple translator/encryptor based on a cipher I made up a while ago as my first project. The idea I had for the cipher is that each character in a string is translated using 4 seperate alternating ciphers and are then combined into the final product. I've already figured out how to translate a string into something with 1 maketrans(table). But I have no clue how I could make my final product be comprised of 4 alternating translation tables.

```py
#My desired table
string = "aabbccdd"
dict1 = {"a":"1," , "b":"2," , "c":"3," , "d":"4,"}
dict2 = {"a":"5," , "b":"6," , "c":"7," , "d":"8,"}
dict3 = {"a":"9," , "b":"10," , "c":"11," , "d":"12,"}
dict4 = {"a":"13," , "b":"14," , "c":"15," , "d":"16,"}
table1 = string.maketrans(dict1)
table2 = string.maketrans(dict2)
table3 = string.maketrans(dict3)
table3 = string.maketrans(dict4)
#The desired result would be "aabbccdd"->"1,5,10,14,3,7,12,16"




#My existing single table
submission = input()
dict1 = {"a":"41","b":"22","c":"13","d":"43"}
    table1 = submission.maketrans(dict1)
    print(submission.translate(table1))
```

My expected result and actual results are visible in the code block. I guess I'm too new to coding to even begin to wrap my head around how this could be done so I was hoping someone could explain to me how I could. Not asking for the solution outright even, but if someone could tell me where to begin that would be a lot of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the pattern of your output example I can suggest to use cycle iterator:

```
from itertools import cycle
string = "aabbccdd"
dict1 = {"a":"1," , "b":"2," , "c":"3," , "d":"4,"}
dict2 = {"a":"5," , "b":"6," , "c":"7," , "d":"8,"}
dict3 = {"a":"9," , "b":"10," , "c":"11," , "d":"12,"}
dict4 = {"a":"13," , "b":"14," , "c":"15," , "d":"16,"}
dicts = cycle([dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4])
encrypted_str = ""
for i in string:
    dict = next(dicts)    #iterates sequentially over the dictionaries
    encrypted_str += dict[i]   #encrypt the letter using random dict and add 
print(encrypted_str[:-1])    #[:-1] to remove the last ","
```

The output: `1,5,10,14,3,7,12,16`

What I though would be interesting is to add some randomity to your encryption. (To decrypt you need to safe the sequence of the dictionaries)
I suggest to write your own translator function.
Here is an example for what I can think about:

```
import random
string = "aabbccdd"
dict1 = {"a":"1," , "b":"2," , "c":"3," , "d":"4,"}
dict2 = {"a":"5," , "b":"6," , "c":"7," , "d":"8,"}
dict3 = {"a":"9," , "b":"10," , "c":"11," , "d":"12,"}
dict4 = {"a":"13," , "b":"14," , "c":"15," , "d":"16,"}
dicts = [dict1, dict2, dict3, dict4]
encrypted_str = ""
for i in string:
    dict = dicts[random.randint(0,3)]  #each iteration choose randomly a new dictionary
    encrypted_str += dict[i]   #encrypt the letter using random dict and add to the encrypted string
print(encrypted_str[:-1])   #[:-1] to remove the last ","
```

The output example is: `13,5,2,6,7,3,12,12`

Comment: This was extroardinarily helpful and worked perfectly for what I was trying to get. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

If using `string.maketrans` and `str.translate` isn't necessary, you can use one dictionary where `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, and `'d'` are the keys, and the values are lists with corresponding numbers, so, value of `'a'` will be `['1', '5', '9', '13']`, value of `'b'` will be `['2', '6', '10', '14']`, and so on, this `dict` can be built using a dict-comprehension, as for the translation, you can use `enumerate`, `str.join`, and the modulo (`%`) operator:

```
alpha = "abcd"

n = len(alpha)

d = {c : [str(j) for j in range(i, n * n + 1, n)] for i, c in enumerate(alpha, 1)}

string = "aabbccdd"

def encrypt(s):
  return ','.join(d[c][i % n] for i, c in enumerate(s))

encrypted = encrypt(string)

print(encrypted)
```

Output:

```
1,5,10,14,3,7,12,16
```

This method works for any alphabet as long as the string being encrypted is in the language generated by that alphabet.